# "Recent Registration" view under CiviEvent - Customise columns

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

Hi to all (and thank you in advance),

I'm looking to add / remove a number of columns under the "Recent Registrations" view, in CiviEvent (image attached).

Any suggestions are welcome.

(running CiviCRM 5.13.4)

Kind regards
A.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That table is defined in templates/CRM/Event/Form/Selector.tpl and changing that would require some level of coding (your profile suggests you have this skill). Changing the Selector.tpl template directly would solve your problem but is discouraged because it causes headaches when upgrading to new versions. Creating an extension is the preferred way to make these kinds of changes, but that is much more involved. (See [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22424/how-to-customize-events-dashboard) for more information.)

A non-coding, quick alternative is create an Event Report with the columns that you want to view, and under that report's Access tab check "Available for Dashboard". That will allow users to add the report to their main Civi Dashboard (rather than the Events Dashboard). That won't get exactly what you want, but may help you solve the usability/workflow issue that I imagine is behind your question.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use the report route for the moment. I am worried about the implications you've mentioned (if I change the *.tpl file) about updates etc.

Comment: You'd just need to manually update the template file every time you run a civi upgrade. Might not be a big deal to you, but it's one more thing to juggle/document.